# Updating a object in a TreeMap (Java)

Tags: java, class, object, treemap

I have a Treemap of people and that treemap is keyed to a name and a person object. That person object has another treemap with more data. I am trying to read data that is not uniform and update said treemap with more data with this code:

```
golfer update = golfers.get(tempName);

course getCourse = courses.get(tempCourse);

tempDiff = (((tempScore - getCourse.rating) * 113) / getCourse.slope);
update.scores.put(tempCalendar, tempDiff);

golfers.put(tempName, update);
```

However, upon running through all the code I find that all the data is wiped and only the most recent entry is in the treemap.

Any thoughts on what is wrong?

Comment: Why do you initialize "update" with new golfer(), then immediately replace it with the golfer from your map?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It will be difficult to answer your question without a working code sample. Please post your code as an [minimal, complete, tested and readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates your problem. Please also note that `TitleCase` is the correct way to name classes in Java.

Comment: tempname is the key. what is tempname? is it the same for all the entries?

Comment: if you find a golfer in your Map, with  golfers.get, then you don't need to put it back in the map after you worked on the golfer. So the last put is useless. But this is not true for the update.scores: here I guess your are storing a new value.

Answer (score 0):

Please note this! `TreeMap`, or any other `Map` implementation for that matter, requires unique `keys`.

So check if the `tempName` variable is being updated to a new value on every iteration. Otherwise it is very obvious that the data will be overwritten and only the last value will be retained.